# How does $\mathbb{E}X_{1}^{2}\mathbb{1}_{|X_{1}|\leq c}=\int_{0}^{c}2x\left[\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>x)-\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>c)\right]dx$?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Consider we have a random variable $X_{1}$, and then we truncated it by $\overline{X}_{1}=X_{1}\mathbb{1}_{|X_{1}|\leq c}$ where $c\geq 1$.

How could I compute $\mathbb{E}\overline{X}_{1}^{2}$?

As usually, we always need the lemma:

> $p>0$, and $Y\geq 0$, we have $$\mathbb{E}Y^{p}=\int_{0}^{\infty}py^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(Y>y)dy.$$

The note I follows directly use this lemma to yield $$\mathbb{E}X_{1}^{2}\mathbb{1}_{|X_{1}|\leq c}=\int_{0}^{c}2x\Big[\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>x)-\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>c)\Big]dx,$$ which I don't quite understand, since this computation is lack of details.

My attempt:

By the lemma, we have $$\mathbb{E}(X_{1}^{2}\mathbb{1}_{|X_{1}|\leq c})=\int_{0}^{\infty}2x\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|\mathbb{1}_{|X_{1}|\leq c}>x)dx,$$ but what should I do, or think, to make this expression the same as the integral provided in the note?

Is there a general way of doing this or is this just by intuition?

I really need an answer which can provide me the calculation details.

Thank you!

Comment: The event you have inside $\mathbb{P}$ is the event that $|X_1| $ is larger than $x$ and no larger than $c$. Note that the bound of integration now changes from $0 $ to $\infty$ to $0$ to $c$. Moreover, under this regime, $\{|X_1| > x \cap |X_1| > c\} = \emptyset $ as we only consider $x$ with $x \in (0, c)$ as given by the integral.

Comment: @rubikscube09 but the truncation is for $|X_{1}|\leq c$ right?

Comment: That's correct. You still need to reweight the probability inside the integral

Comment: @rubikscube09 oh! so you mean, $$\int_{0}^{\infty}2x\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|\mathbb{1}_{|X_{1}\leq c}>x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}2x\mathbb{P}(x<|X_{1}|\leq c)dx=\int_{0}^{c}2x\mathbb{P}(x<|X_{1}|\leq c)dx=\int_{0}^{c}2x\Big[\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>x)-\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>c)\Big]dx?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Fubini's theorem. You can rewrite 
\begin{aligned}
\int_\Omega X^2(\omega)\mathbf{1}(||X(\omega)|\leq c)\mathbb{P}(d\omega)&=\int_\Omega\Big(\mathbb{1}(|X(\omega)|\leq c)\int\mathbf{1}(0<t< |X(\omega)|)\,2t\,dt\Big)\mathbf{P}(d\omega)\\
&=\int_{(0,\infty)}2t\Big(\int_\Omega \mathbb{1}(|X(\omega)|\leq c)\mathbf{1}(0<t< |X(\omega)|)\mathbb{P}(d\omega)\Big) dt
\end{aligned}

For $0<t<\infty$, 
$$\mathbb{1}(|X(\omega)|\leq c)\mathbf{1}(0<t\leq |X(\omega)|)=\mathbf{1}(t<|X(\omega)|\leq c)$$
So
\begin{aligned}
\int_{(0,\infty)}2t\Big(\int_\Omega \mathbb{1}(|X(\omega)|\leq c)\mathbf{1}(0<t< |X(\omega)|)\mathbb{P}(d\omega)\Big) dt&=\int^\infty_0 2t \Big(\int_\Omega\mathbf{1}(t<|X(\omega)|\leq c)\mathbb{P}(d\omega)\Big)\,dt\\
&=\int^\infty_0 2t(\mathbb{P}(t<|X(\omega)|\leq c)\,dt\\
&=\int^\infty_0 2t(\mathbb{P}(|X|>t) -\mathbf{P}(|X|> c))\,dt
\end{aligned}

Comment: then how to go from your rewriting to the integral provided in the note above?

Comment: Just added more steps. Now try to deal with the most inner integral.

Comment: I think the problem here is that I don't know how to deal with the inner integral. You are definitely right about the Fubini, since the lemma I provided in my post was proved by using Fubini.

Comment: just added more detail. Hope this helps

Comment: I was outside so I only accepted your answer and voted without expressing my appreciation. Thank you so much for your brilliant answer :)!